# How to trigger change event for Chosen (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Before I click reset button I choose "Company" in Chosen (dropdown list). The event occurs normally after I click reset. I choose "Company" again but event `change` in dropdownlist doesn't occur.

Could anyone tell me how to trigger the change event for dropdownlist after clicking reset button and then the same element?

The code I have so far:

```
$("#mainMenu").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadFirstManu(true);
});
```

Code for the reset button:

```
$("#btn_reset").click(function() {
  CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.setData('');
  $('.mchosen').each(function() {
     $(this).val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
     $('#submenu').attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('');
     $('#secondsubmenu').attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('');
     $('#s-menu').removeClass('required').html('');
     $('#secondsubmenu').removeClass('validate[required]');
     $('#tabmenu').attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('');
     $('#tab').removeClass('required').html('');
  });
```

});

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is what i figured out:

```
$('#my-select').val(5).trigger("liszt:updated")
```

`liszt:updated` is no longer working in new version of chosen instead use below as [Alexandru Cojan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25934664/1723893) answer  suggesting

```
 trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. This is the new trigger name convention  for 1.0, as stated in [the Change Notes](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/tag/1.0.0).

Answer (score 10):

for newer version of chosen the event is "chosen:updated"

```
$(selector).trigger("chosen:updated")
```

Answer (score 10):

If i need just to refresh value in chosen select - `.trigger('chosen:updated')` is enough. But if I have change handler and want it to be called - i need to do `.trigger('chosen:updated').change()`

Comment: This is what i needed.. I had a change event tied to my chosen DDL and this `.trigger('chosen:updated').change()` helped me achieve calling the change function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case or not, but your code above should work,

```
$("#mainMenu").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        loadFirstManu(true);
    });
```

but please notice that "change" event occurs on most browsers when you **unfocus** the select input

So when you click **reset**, just before executing the reset action the **onchange** is triggered.

Now try clicking outside the select input after changing the selection and see if it still works or not

Comment: the event occur before i click reset button after that i select the element that i have chosen before click reset it's no event occur.

Comment: Since, I don't know the structure of your html/code, you can add something like alert("triggered"); in the .change() function you're using to know where's the error exactly

Comment: after click reset and the same element before click reset event not occur i have also put alert("Hello") to detect the event occur or not finally still not occur.

Comment: try to remove e.preventDefault I don't think it has any use here in the select

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using .on, as your $('#mainMenu') may have changed somewhere (Can't say without an example). Try doing this:

```
$("body").on('change','#mainMenu',function(){ 
  ...
});
```

or any parent selector instead of "heavy" body

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong to understand you then you want to trigger the event change after click on the reset button.
         you can do this by simply adding one line to your code
         //code

```
     $("#btn_reset").click(function(){
       // your code here
       $("#mainMenu").trigger('change'); 
       //you can write this as per your requirements ie. at start or end.

      });
```